# Uniform grid implementation

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, game

Could you, please highlight technical (performance), style and best-practice using problems (if any) on this code? I'm not a pro, just wrote uniform grid implementation for my 2d game with C++11 and I want to increase my code-writing skills knowing my mistakes. Will glad to accept some useful critics. The grid is written for dynamically moving objects.

```
// SizeI and PositionF are std::pair's.

#include <forward_list>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace internal
{

template <typename T, bool isPtr>
struct TTraits
{
  using TPtr = T*;
};

template <typename T>
struct TTraits<T, true>
{
  using TPtr = T;
};

} // namespace internal

template <typename T>
class UniformGrid
{
public:
  using ObjId = Id;
  using TPtr = typename internal::TTraits<T, std::is_pointer<T>::value>::TPtr;

public:
  UniformGrid(int32_t w, int32_t h, float cellW, float cellH):
    mCellW(cellW), mCellH(cellH), mW(w), mH(h)
  {
  }

  constexpr int32_t getW() const
  {
    return mW;
  }

  constexpr int32_t getH() const
  {
    return mH;
  }

  ObjId insert(const T &r)
  {
    createBindings(r);
    const ObjId objId = getObjId(r);
    mObjs.insert(std::make_pair(objId, r));
    return objId;
  }

  ObjId insert(T &&r)
  {
    createBindings(r);
    const ObjId objId = getObjId(r);
    mObjs.emplace(objId, std::move(r));
    return objId;
  }

  void remove(ObjId id)
  {
    typename std::unordered_map<ObjId, T>::iterator it = mObjs.find(id);
    if (it == mObjs.end())
      return;

    removeBindings(it->second);
    mObjs.erase(it);
  }

  void update(ObjId objId)
  {
    auto it = mObjs.find(objId);
    if (it == mObjs.end())
      return;

    removeBindings(it->second);
    createBindings(it->second);
  }

  void clear()
  {
    mObjs.clear();
    mObjCells.clear();
    mCellObjs.clear();
  }

  using size_type = typename std::unordered_map<ObjId, T>::size_type;
  size_type getSize() const
  {
    return mObjs.size();
  }

  bool isEmpty() const
  {
    return mObjs.empty();
  }

  bool hasObjects() const
  {
    return mObjs.size() > 0;
  }

  void updateVisibleObjects(float x, float y, float w, float h)
  {
    mVisibleObjects.clear();
    const TargetCells tc = getTargetCells(x, y, w, h);
    for (typename TargetCells::Type i = tc.StartY; i <= tc.EndY; ++i)
    {
      for (typename TargetCells::Type j = tc.StartX; j <= tc.EndX; ++j)
      {
        const auto &iters = mCellObjs.equal_range(getCellId(i, j));
        if (iters.first != iters.second)
        {
          for (auto i = iters.first; i != iters.second; ++i)
            pushToVisible(*i, std::is_pointer<T>());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool hasVisibleObjects() const
  {
    return !mVisibleObjects.empty();
  }

  using VisibleObjContainer = std::forward_list<TPtr>;
  using VisibleObjIt = typename VisibleObjContainer::iterator;
  using VisibleObjCIt = typename VisibleObjContainer::const_iterator;

  VisibleObjIt begin()
  {
    return mVisibleObjects.begin();
  }

  // Other iterators...

private:
  struct TargetCells
  {
    using Type = int32_t;
    Type StartX = 0, EndX = 0, StartY = 0, EndY = 0;
  };
  using CellId = uint32_t;

private:
  // todo Use std::enable_if
  void pushToVisible(const std::pair<CellId, ObjId> &i, const std::true_type&)
  {
    mVisibleObjects.push_front(mObjs[i.second]);
  }

  void pushToVisible(const std::pair<CellId, ObjId> &i, const std::false_type&)
  {
    mVisibleObjects.push_front(&mObjs[i.second]);
  }

  constexpr uint32_t getCellId(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
  {
    return x * mW + y;
  }

  // Find out which cells this object occupies.
  const TargetCells getTargetCells(const T &obj) const
  {
    const SizeI objSize = getObjSize(obj);
    const PositionF objPos = getObjPos(obj);
    return getTargetCells(objPos.first, objPos.second, objSize.first, objSize.second);
  }

  // Finds out which cells are visible under the camera.
  const TargetCells getTargetCells(float x, float y, float w, float h) const
  {
    TargetCells tc;
    tc.StartX = x / mCellW;
    tc.EndX = (x + w) / mCellW;
    tc.StartY = y / mCellH;
    tc.EndY = (y + h) / mCellH;
    correctCells(tc);
    return tc;
  }

  inline void correctCells(TargetCells &tc) const
  {
    if (tc.StartX < 0) tc.StartX = 0;
    if (tc.StartY < 0) tc.StartY = 0;
    if (tc.EndX >= mW) tc.EndX = mW;
    if (tc.EndY >= mH) tc.EndY = mH;
  }

  void removeObjFromCell(CellId cellId, ObjId objId)
  {
    auto range = mCellObjs.equal_range(cellId);
    for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    {
      if (it->second == objId)
      {
        mCellObjs.erase(it);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  void createBindings(const T &obj)
  {
    const TargetCells tc = getTargetCells(obj);
    const ObjId objId = getObjId(obj);
    for (int32_t i = tc.StartY; i <= tc.EndY; ++i)
    {
      for (int32_t j = tc.StartX; j <= tc.EndX; ++j)
      {
        mObjCells.insert(std::make_pair(objId, getCellId(i, j)));
        mCellObjs.insert(std::make_pair(getCellId(i, j), objId));
      }
    }
  }

  void removeBindings(const T &obj)
  {
    const ObjId objId = getObjId(obj);

    // Here we should get cells occupied by object.
    const auto &range = mObjCells.equal_range(objId);

    std::for_each(range.first, range.second,
      [objId, this] (const std::pair<ObjId, CellId> &i)
      {
        removeObjFromCell(i.second, objId);
      });
    mObjCells.erase(objId);
  }

// todo Use std::enable_if
  ObjId getObjId(const T &obj) const
  {
    return getObjIdHelper(obj, std::integral_constant<bool, IsAnyPtr<T>::value>());
  }

  ObjId getObjIdHelper(const T &obj, const std::false_type&) const
  {
    return obj.getId();
  }

  ObjId getObjIdHelper(const T &obj, const std::true_type&) const
  {
    return obj->getId();
  }

  PositionF getObjPos(const T &obj) const
  {
    return getObjPosHelper(obj, std::integral_constant<bool, IsAnyPtr<T>::value>());
  }

  PositionF getObjPosHelper(const T &obj, const std::false_type&) const
  {
    return obj.getTileComponent().getPos();
  }

  PositionF getObjPosHelper(const T &obj, const std::true_type&) const
  {
    return obj->getTileComponent().getPos();
  }

  SizeI getObjSize(const T &obj) const
  {
    return getObjSizeHelper(obj, std::integral_constant<bool, IsAnyPtr<T>::value>());
  }

  SizeI getObjSizeHelper(const T &obj, const std::false_type&) const
  {
    return obj.getTileComponent().getSize();
  }

  SizeI getObjSizeHelper(const T &obj, const std::true_type&) const
  {
    return obj->getTileComponent().getSize();
  }

private:
  std::unordered_multimap<ObjId, CellId> mObjCells;
  std::unordered_multimap<CellId, ObjId> mCellObjs;
  std::unordered_map<ObjId, T> mObjs;
  VisibleObjContainer mVisibleObjects;
  float mCellW = 0.f, mCellH = 0.f;
  int32_t mW = 0, mH = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this code somewhat hard to understand at first. If I'm understanding it correctly, it keeps track of a set of objects that cover some cells of a grid, and allows a user of the class to insert objects into the grid and then figure out if a given object is in a particular cell. Is that right? So in a game it could be used for collision detection, for example. Assuming I understand it correctly, here are my thoughts.

## Use Types

Your comment says:

```
// SizeI and PositionF are std::pair's.
```

This is a bad idea. `std::pair` has 2 elements that don't need to be the same type. They have generic names that are meaningless to almost all code. Two dimensional sizes and positions need 2 values that are the same type and should be distinguished from one another by proper names. You should use a `struct` or `class` for these types (or better yet, use an existing one on the system you're working on). I recommend something like this:

```
struct SizeI {
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
};
struct PositionF {
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

If it were me, I would probably make actual typedefs for them. In fact, a position usually warrants a full-blown class because you often need to add and subtract coordinates and calculate distances between them, etc.

If you're writing any graphics code, you will likely already have some sort of point or vector structure available from your graphics library, so you should just use those.

## Naming

Some of your names are pretty decent, like `cellW` and `cellH` in the constructor. But some of them could be more descriptive. For example, are `w` and `h` the number of cells wide and number of cells high? Or are they the width and height in some units (like pixels)? I would name them `numRows` and `numColumns` or `numCellsWide` and `numCellsHigh`. Likewise, `getW()` and `getH()` should be renamed to `getNumRows()` and `getNumColumns()`.

In the `insert()` methods, what is `r`? I realize that since this is a template, it can be of any type, but I can't even figure out what `r` stands for in the generic sense.

What's the difference between `isEmpty()` and `hasObjects()`? If a `std::unordered_map<>` has a `size` of 0, isn't it also empty? My implementation says these are the same thing. I'd remove one unless there's a really good reason why users of this class would expect to have both.

You have 3 different types of maps with confusingly similar names. Looking at `mObjCell` and `mCellObjs`, I'm pretty sure I'd get confused as to which one to use.

## Reduce Verbosity

What is the purpose of this?

```
  struct TargetCells
  {
    using Type = int32_t;
    Type StartX = 0, EndX = 0, StartY = 0, EndY = 0;
  };
```

You define `Type` (which is a terrible name because all types are types, so which type does `Type` refer to?) as `int32_t`, then use it to define 4 members of the `struct`. It's not ever used again. Why not just define the members as `int32_t` directly?

I would remove the `correctCells()` method and just use `std::min()` and `std::max()` inline in `getTargetCells()`. By the way, can `StartX` or `StartY` ever be larger than `mW` or `mH` if `x` or `y` gets too large?

## Don't Repeat Yourself

There's a lot of code that does the same thing twice - once for direct objects and once for pointers. Do you really need to support both? If so, should they be a single class or would it make more sense to put the stuff that's only used once into a base class, and have a subclass for pointer objects and a different subclass for direct objects? (Or would composition be better - 2 unrelated classes that both contain an object which has the shared stuff?) Without more information about how it's used, I can't say, but it feels off to have so much almost-duplicate code.

Comment: Sorry for being absent a long time. Thank your very much - your comments really helped  me.